# Terminology: what is a (re)grade

Tags: terminology

I the article [Foundations of Inference by Knuth and Skilling](http://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/1/1/38/htm) terms "grade" and "regrade" appear, apparently applied to an $\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ function (named $\Theta$ in the article). Basic search on wikipedia/google didn't return much.

So my question is what are the definitions of "regrade" and "grade".

Disclaimer: I'm not native English speaker.

Comment: That's **Kevin** Knuth.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown is this a suggestion on attribution formatting?